# Why am I getting "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" even though doing what the Spring documentation suggests

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, header, cors

I'm trying to create an application like this [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/boot/oauth2authorizationserver), but I'm having problems with CORS.

I already did what was suggested here [CORS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#cors), but I'm getting this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://writer:secret@localhost:8081/oauth/token' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My classes:

```
package br.com.sammubr.auth;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
package br.com.sammubr.auth.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultAccessTokenConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore;

import java.security.KeyPair;

@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    KeyPair keyPair;
    boolean jwtEnabled;

    public AuthorizationServerConfiguration(
            AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration,
            KeyPair keyPair,
            @Value("${security.oauth2.authorizationserver.jwt.enabled:true}") boolean jwtEnabled) throws Exception {

        this.authenticationManager = authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
        this.keyPair = keyPair;
        this.jwtEnabled = jwtEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("reader")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                .secret("{noop}secret")
                .scopes("message:read")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(600_000_000)
                .and()
                .withClient("writer")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                .secret("{noop}secret")
                .scopes("message:write")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(600_000_000)
                .and()
                .withClient("noscopes")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                .secret("{noop}secret")
                .scopes("none")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(600_000_000);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {

        endpoints
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore());

        if (this.jwtEnabled) {
            endpoints
                    .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        if (this.jwtEnabled) {
            return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
        } else {
            return new InMemoryTokenStore();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setKeyPair(this.keyPair);

        DefaultAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
        accessTokenConverter.setUserTokenConverter(new SubjectAttributeUserTokenConverter());
        converter.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter);

        return converter;
    }
}
```

```
package br.com.sammubr.auth.configuration;

import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.FrameworkEndpoint;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@FrameworkEndpoint
class IntrospectEndpoint {
    TokenStore tokenStore;

    IntrospectEndpoint(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
    }

    @PostMapping("/introspect")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> introspect(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = this.tokenStore.readAccessToken(token);
        Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
        if (accessToken == null || accessToken.isExpired()) {
            attributes.put("active", false);
            return attributes;
        }

        OAuth2Authentication authentication = this.tokenStore.readAuthentication(token);

        attributes.put("active", true);
        attributes.put("exp", accessToken.getExpiration().getTime());
        attributes.put("scope", accessToken.getScope().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
        attributes.put("sub", authentication.getName());

        return attributes;
    }
}
```

```
package br.com.sammubr.auth.configuration;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.FrameworkEndpoint;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.Map;

@FrameworkEndpoint
class JwkSetEndpoint {
    KeyPair keyPair;

    JwkSetEndpoint(KeyPair keyPair) {
        this.keyPair = keyPair;
    }

    @GetMapping("/.well-known/jwks.json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> getKey() {
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) this.keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAKey key = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey).build();
        return new JWKSet(key).toJSONObject();
    }
}
```

```
package br.com.sammubr.auth.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;

@Configuration
class KeyConfig {
    @Bean
    KeyPair keyPair() {
        try {
            String privateExponent = "3851612021791312596791631935569878540203393691253311342052463788814433805390794604753109719790052408607029530149004451377846406736413270923596916756321977922303381344613407820854322190592787335193581632323728135479679928871596911841005827348430783250026013354350760878678723915119966019947072651782000702927096735228356171563532131162414366310012554312756036441054404004920678199077822575051043273088621405687950081861819700809912238863867947415641838115425624808671834312114785499017269379478439158796130804789241476050832773822038351367878951389438751088021113551495469440016698505614123035099067172660197922333993";
            String modulus = "18044398961479537755088511127417480155072543594514852056908450877656126120801808993616738273349107491806340290040410660515399239279742407357192875363433659810851147557504389760192273458065587503508596714389889971758652047927503525007076910925306186421971180013159326306810174367375596043267660331677530921991343349336096643043840224352451615452251387611820750171352353189973315443889352557807329336576421211370350554195530374360110583327093711721857129170040527236951522127488980970085401773781530555922385755722534685479501240842392531455355164896023070459024737908929308707435474197069199421373363801477026083786683";
            String exponent = "65537";

            RSAPublicKeySpec publicSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(modulus), new BigInteger(exponent));
            RSAPrivateKeySpec privateSpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(new BigInteger(modulus), new BigInteger(privateExponent));
            KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            return new KeyPair(factory.generatePublic(publicSpec), factory.generatePrivate(privateSpec));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
package br.com.sammubr.auth.configuration;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class SubjectAttributeUserTokenConverter extends DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter {
    @Override
    public Map<String, ?> convertUserAuthentication(Authentication authentication) {
        Map<String, Object> response = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        response.put("sub", authentication.getName());
        if (authentication.getAuthorities() != null && !authentication.getAuthorities().isEmpty()) {
            response.put(AUTHORITIES, AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities()));
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

```
package br.com.sammubr.auth.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
class UserConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(withDefaults())
                .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/.well-known/jwks.json").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers(request -> "/introspect".equals(request.getRequestURI()));
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("subject")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build());
    }
}
```

And my request is simple like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;

import axios from "axios";

let api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://writer:secret@localhost:8081',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=submit]").on("click", function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('username', 'subject');
        params.append('password', 'password');
        params.append('grant_type', 'password');

        api.post('/oauth/token', params)
        .then((resp) => {
            console.log(resp.data)
        }).catch(error => console.error(error));

    });
});
```

I'm doing what you say in the Spring documentation, but it's not working. Can someone help me?

Comment: your issue is with cors, no need to post your whole app source code. To see if the cors configuration is problematic (like you seem to disallow request `withCredentials`), the javadoc states `Use applyPermitDefaultValues() to flip the initialization model to start with open defaults that permit all cross-origin requests for GET, HEAD, and POST requests.`. I would start there.

Comment: Could you check by adding  '@EnableWebSecurity` i did not find that
'

Comment: @cghislai I tried and it didn't work. The same error continues.

Comment: @NirajSonawane This example of Spring https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/boot/oauth2authorizationserver has no EnableWebSecurity. And even putting it, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker No status, only (failed) net::ER_FAILED in network tab. In console tab, i'm getting ```Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://writer:secret@localhost:8081/oauth/token' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
entry.js:26 Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)
xhr.js:178 POST http://writer:secret@localhost:8081/oauth/token net::ERR_FAILED```

Comment: @dur https://imgur.com/a/PrCzhRd